# How do you get a location from the GoogleMaps app and use it in your own app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm trying to retrieve a target location from the GoogleMaps app and use it in my own app, but so far I could not find any documentation about how to do it.

For a more detailed description: If you start your google maps app and long-press any location on the map, a marker is set on that location. If you tap that marker, the details for that location are shown. Amongst other things, there is a "SHARE" button in these details. When you tap that button, a list of apps is displayed that are able to accept the shared location. I want my app to appear there!

I figured: Since this information will be sent as an intent, I need to register my app as an intent filter for the appropriate intent. But **what intents do I need to listen to?**

In the manifest it would look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="My Activity">
    <intent-filter android:label="My App">
        <!-- What goes here? -->
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Once I got this, I'm expecting my app to appear in the mentioned list. Next step is to process the received data. So, **What does the data look like, that I get from the intent?** **Is there any default API to process this data?**

Any help is appreciated. I know I cannot offer a lot of details in the sense of "What I tried so far", but I really couldn't find an API description that would have helped me here.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html.

You'll need to:

1. Update your activity's intent filter in your manifest

   ```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
2. Add code to your activity to handle the intent

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String action = intent.getAction();
   String type = intent.getType();

   if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
       String text = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
       // Do whatever you want with the text
   }
   ```